# Is the path from u to v is diameter of the tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

The diameter of a tree is the longest (simple) path in the tree. Let u be a vertex in a tree and let v be the farthest from u vertex in T. Show
that the path from u to v may not be a diameter
I am getting confused of how to find this?

Comment: What happens if $u$ is not a leaf?

Comment: You need to describe (define/draw) a tree $T$ with vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $v$ is farthest from $u$, but the distance from $u$ to $v$ is not the diameter of $T$.

Comment: Let $T$ be a star on more than 2 vertices and let $u$ be the vertex of maximum degree. Then $v$ would be a leaf and $d(u,v)=1$ which is not equal to the diameter of graph.